# Input to print output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get it to print out nice and ugly when the user enters them but it only remembers the last input from the user.

```
n = int(input('How many groups would you like to configure today?'))
for i in range(n):
    group = input('Group {}: '.format(i+1))

def uqdfa(money):
    return('permit ' + money)

if group == 'nice':
    print (uqdfa('233.10.10.10'))
    print (uqdfa('233.10.10.11'))

if group == 'ugly':
    print (uqdfa('233.10.10.16'))
    print (uqdfa('233.10.10.17'))
```

Answer (score 3):

`if` block should be inside the `for` loop.

```
def uqdfa(money):
    return('permit ' + money)

n = int(input('How many groups would you like to configure today?'))
for i in range(n):
    group = input('Group {}: '.format(i+1))
    if group == 'nice':
        print (uqdfa('233.10.10.10'))
        print (uqdfa('233.10.10.11'))

    elif group == 'ugly':
        print (uqdfa('233.10.10.16'))
        print (uqdfa('233.10.10.17'))
```